# Python flask using variables from config.py in javascript file

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, flask, import

I am trying to reuse some of my variables from my `config.py` in my javascript files, specifically `WEBSERVER_HOST` and `WEBSERVER_PORT` variables. My `config.py` looks like this:

config.py

```
# Webserver configs
WEBSERVER_HOST = 'myhost'
WEBSERVER_PORT = 5000
```

In my js file I declare these on the top of my js file like this:

app.js:

```
var HOST = 'myhost'; // I want this var HOST = WEBSERVER_HOST;
var PORT = 5000;     // and this var PORT = WEBSERVER_PORT;
```

I can import `config.py` in a regular python file (e,g. `run.py`), but I would like to know if I can somehow also import these values into my javascript files as well so I don't have to declare them twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is to move that `.js` file out of `/static/` into `templates/`, add a route to it, and rework it to read

```
var HOST = "{{ host }}";
var PORT = {{ port }};
```

Then add a route to `app.js` and do

```
@app.route('app.js')
def app_js():
    return render_template('app.js',
                           host=app.config['WEBSERVER_HOST'],
                           port=app.config['WEBSERVER_PORT'])
```

An alternative is to inject those into your `.html` templates, arranging for them to land with `<script>...</script>` elements.